# Connecting to office 365 outlook shared mailbox is not working with IMAP. DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO LOGIN failed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, outlook, office365, imap

```
public class EmailTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
    
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.host", "outlook.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.imaps.port", 993);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);
        Store _store = session.getStore("imaps");



        _store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "userName@domain.onmicrosoft.com\\sharedemail",
                "password");

        Folder inbox = _store.getFolder("INBOX");
        // inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println(messageCount);
```

This code was working before however from last 20 days it stopped working with below error. We enabled "enable less secure apps and also tried using app password instead of regular password still couldn't figure out. Can someone help please?

```
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=magnusNG@domain.onmicrosoft.com\magnustestngmha, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO LOGIN failed.
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:661)
```

It was supposed to connect to outlook shared account and get message count however failing with above error message

Comment: You cannot use passwords to login to Office365 anymore.  This change has been warned about for years: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

Comment: Thanks for responsding @Max, I have also tried with app password which i mentioned as part of question.. still i am getting same error message

Comment: Try to set `mail.debug.auth` to `true` and see detailed information that may help you to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Basic oauth has been deprecated by microsoft. You can use ROPC flow to connect with username and password with AAD application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc
This is less secure flow if more secure flow needed then please use client credentails or authorization code with pkce flow.